# React Native Background Websockets/MQTT

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, push-notification, mqtt

What is the proper way to show notifications of the message's received from mqtt/websockets when app is running in the background or when app is closed using react native.

So far I have achieved to show notifications when app is in the foreground using [react-native-paho-mqtt](https://github.com/rh389/react-native-paho-mqtt) as mqtt client and [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) for showing notifications

Answer (score 0):

If the app is running in foreground, then you show message received from socket as "**Snackbar**" or "**Toast**" or other way.
If  the app is running in background, then the message received from socket should appear as **push-notification** for your application.

Comment: Alright, But how to run and listen to socket events in the background

Comment: socket events (in JS) doesn't work good in when app is in background, for that you can write some native code, so that it works fine.
Like the NPM react-native-fcm works very well for showing push-notification when app is in background/killed, and when app is in foreground you can do whatever you want on the basis of message received from server.

Comment: You can't run code when the app is in the background, after a couple of minutes the OS will terminate everything (except for Android services, but please don't do that for showing notifications) - Use Push Notifications instead, and not mqtt for that.